# Determinant is 1 implies rank of derivative is 1?

Tags: analysis, derivatives

Is it true that if the determinant of any $n\times n$ matrix is 1, then the rank of the derivative of the matrix is also 1?

If this is the case, how would one prove it?

(Edit: This needs to hold for all $n$)

Comment: $$\frac d{dt}I = 0$$

Comment: Edited my question

Comment: @Ad22 as the other comment exemplifies, the answer is no

Comment: My apologies. I misread the earlier comment. This might be a stupid question but what about when $n \geq 2$

Comment: That was a pretty stupid question. Sorry!

Comment: What is the derivative of a matrix? I don't see any variables here to talk of differentiation.